# Shell script not able to awk created file

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create some simple pass/fail test scripts, but I am having some challenges as outlined below. My intent is to get the full results of a command (such as ping) into a `results.txt` file to keep, but also parse the `results.txt` file for different checks to raise if issues are detected:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 20 google.com > results.txt
packetloss = `awk '/packet loss/{x=$6} END{print x}' results.txt`
echo "$packetloss" >> debug.txt
#  if packetloss > 0, add to an error.txt to fail
#  if avg ping time > 5ms, add to an error.txt to fail
```

The packetloss variable is not getting the [`awk`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) information from the `results.txt` file (sending to a debug file to review). I was wondering if there is something about shell scripting that would prevent this and an associated workaround?

Manually running `awk` on `results.txt` returns '0%' which is the expected result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed around `=`!

So:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -c 20 google.com > results.txt
packetloss=$(awk '/packet loss/{print $6}' results.txt)
echo "$packetloss" >> debug.txt
```

Or even shorter:

```
ping -c 20 google.com |
    awk '/packet loss/{sub(/%/, "");print $6 >> "debug.txt"}'
```

#### NOTE:

- There is no need to assign the `x` variable; you can print `$6` directly.
- AWK itself can create new files with its output
- The backquote

  ```
  `
  ```

  is used in the old-style command substitution, for example :

```
foo=`command`
```

The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest.

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

#### Extra solution using [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl):

```
ping -c 20 google.com |
    perl -lne '/(\d+)%\s+packet\s+loss/ and print $1' >> debug.txt
```

Comment: bingo - that must be the number one problem with compiled language programmers trying to write scripts :-P

Comment: just for extra, is there a way to use awk to never show '%' or similar characters?

Comment: Yes, POST edited accordingly, check `sub()`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $host=shift or die("Usage $0 host\n");

open(PING , "-|", "ping -c 20 $host") or die;
open(DEBUG, ">>", "debug.txt"       ) or die; 

while(<PING>){
  if(m!(\d+)% packet loss!     ){ $Lost=$1 }
  if(m!rtt.*= (.+?)/(.+?)/(.+)!){ $Avg=$2  }
}

if   ( $Lost > 0 ) { print DEBUG "not ok: lost pcks ($Lost%)\n"    }
elsif( $Avg  > 5 ) { print DEBUG "not ok: too slow  ($Avg)\n"      }
else               { print DEBUG "ok: ping\n"                      }
```

Comment: Global file-handles should be avoided. Instead use : `open my $debug, ">>", "debug.txt" or die $!; `

Comment: @sputnick: thank you. You are right or course. I was just trying to make it look simpler... (always a dangerous choice) :)